# How to import a csv file without column name row in DolphinDB database

Tags: dolphindb

I need to import a large csv file with no column name row in DolphinDB. What's the easiest way to do it? I saw on their website an example that we can update the schema file. Not sure if it's the best way to do it as the csv file has many columns.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to load the csv file and then rename table columns.

```
t = loadText(file).rename!(newColNames)
```